# Setting max speed of collisions

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are sharp edges in the imported collada mesh I am running my robot in and when the robot collides with the edges it gets launched in the air and flies far away.

Is there a parameter I can set to reduce the max speed or force imparted on the robot from collisions?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15654/setting-max-speed-of-collisions/) by [matwilso](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2928/matwilso/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe that would be [max_vel](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=collision#ode_max_vel).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1